# R: testing linear combination of coefficients from multiple regressions with plm

Tags: r, linear-regression, plm

I would like to calculate confidence intervals for a sum of coefficients from different regressions

With `n=2`:

```
plm(y ~ x ...)
plm(y ~ z ...)
```

I'd need the confidence interval for the point estimate of `beta(x)+beta(z)`, where `beta()` are the coefficients from the two regressions.

How to go about this?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you assuming these coefficients `beta(x)` and `beta(z)` are independent?  Also, this may be theoretical enough to be a better question for CrossValidated (sort of like [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31442/calculating-the-confidence-interval-for-simple-linear-regression-coefficient-est)).