# Is there a way in R to create a linear combination of coefficients from **different** lm models?

Tags: r, combinations

Unfortunately, I can't provide the data I'm working with, but I don't think it's necessary to solve the problem. My question is, I think, the same one this guy had 5 years ago ([R: testing linear combination of coefficients from multiple regressions with plm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34790253/r-testing-linear-combination-of-coefficients-from-multiple-regressions-with-plm)), but back then it went unanswered, so I'll try my luck.

Essentially, as the title says, I want to test for a linear combination of coefficients. This sounds very straightforward and indeed there are several packages to do so (glht, lincom, etc.). The only problem is that all of them take as one of the arguments a single lm (or glm, etc.) model, whereas I am estimating several models and I want to compute point estimates, se, etc. from a linear combination of coefficients of **different** previously estimated models.

In Stata, this is done with a simple trick which is running first *suest* command which takes as argument model names and combines them in one single object, and then running *lincom* as one would do in R. I have been searching the internet for a while and couldn't find anything, do you know how to achieve this in R?

Here is a more concrete example of what I want to do, I hope it helps.

```
library(data.table)
library(estimatr)
library(foreign)
library(multcomp)

df <- data.table(y1 = runif(100, 0, 100),
                 y2 = runif(100, 0, 100),
                 y3 = runif(100, 0, 100),
                 x  = runif(100, 0, 100),
                 z  = runif(100, 0, 100),
                 id = round(runif(100, 0, 100)/10)*10)

lm1 <- lm_robust(formula  = y1 ~ x + z, 
                 data     = df, 
                 subset   = x>10 & x<90, 
                 clusters = id)
lm2 <- lm_robust(formula  = y2 ~ x + z, 
                 data     = df, 
                 subset   = x>10 & x<90, 
                 clusters = id)
lm3 <- lm_robust(formula  = y3 ~ x + z, 
                 data     = df, 
                 subset   = x>10 & x<90, 
                 clusters = id)

# linear combination I can for example do
summary(glht(lm1, linfct = "x + z = 0"))

# linear combination I would like to do
# 0.1*z_lm1 + 0.4*z_lm2 + 0.2*z_lm3 = 0, where the numbers before the coefficients are weights defined somewhere else
```

I now read in the *glht* documentation that by passing to the function a list of coefficients and a covariance matrix it should be able to ignore the "model" argument and thus let me compute a linear combination of coefficients from different models. However, I still have no idea how one would go about computing a covariance matrix using results from different models.

Comment: If you can't share your data create a small artificial example using random numbers or a dataset that comes with R.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Are you trying to build an ensemble model and use that for predictions?